# How can I restrict access to a file on OSS while still allowing download using wget or curl

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-oss

I have created a large file (disk image) on OSS.  I am able to download it with a browser using a hotlink (temporary time limited url).  However I am unable to download to another server using wget and curl with the same url (error 403): "you have no right to access this object because of bucket acl".

In this answer: [stop oss links from expiring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728996/how-do-i-stop-object-storage-service-file-links-from-expiring) it is stated that setting public or public-read ACL on the object or bucket is the only way to do this.  If I do make it public, can I also set up whitelisting for the destination server to prevent others from downloading the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [doc](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/85111.htm), you can use IP based bucket policy to restrict the access from certain IP addresses.

[image]